# Equalizer in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, alsa, 18.04, equalizer

Is there any build in Equalizer in Ubuntu 18.04 or a third party program that works with this version best?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[PulseEffects](https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects#gnulinux-packages) application has a system-wide equalizer that you can control on a per-application basis. The application also provides various sound effects / enhancements, like limiter, compressor, reverberation, equalizer and auto volume effects.

A tweak is needed for PulseEffects to work correctly in Ubuntu, see [here](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/05/pulseeffects-nice-system-wide.html).

Oh, here's a screenshot:

[image]

Edit: to install PulseEffects follow the setup Flatpak and Flathub using this [quick guide](https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/). Then visit the [PulseEffects FlatHub page](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.github.wwmm.pulseeffects) and click install. You can also search for PulseEffects in Ubuntu Software (after setting up Flatpak and Flathub like I mentioned).

Comment: Question. How do I install this? I don't know where to begin and there doesn't appear to be any clear instructions?

Comment: @PaulBenson I updated my answer to include installation instructions.

Comment: Thnx. But I have a zip file that was downloaded from Github, (used the download button there). But there is nothing to tell me how to install from that - eg there is no install file and no read-me instructions included, so I'm still none the wiser.

Comment: @PaulBenson use the Flatpak like I mentioned, not the zip. The zip needs building from source and that's quite complicated.

Comment: Seems broken for at least 6 months - I get a seg fault and it seems like others have the same issue (see comments in the next answer down)

Comment: @JonnyRaa How are you installing it and from where? I installed it only last week on a Linux Mint system, and there's no '*segmentation fault*' error.

Comment: @PaulBenson did you use the flatpak method described here?  I think I followed the instructions in the next answer down as it seemed more recent.  The state I got into was that it was installed but not working and then I tried some things I can't remember now based on googling seg fault in pulse effects which didn't fix the issue

Comment: No, I didn't. I installed using the ppa:mikhailnov repo and it worked fine then. Some months ago I also did the the same on Linux Mint and again it worked OK. I will uninstall it over the next 24 hours then re-install to see if I get this segmentation error that some have mentioned.

Comment: I'm on ubuntu 18.04 ... could be because of that

Comment: @JonnyRaa No, I'm on 18.04 too. I uninstalled PulseEffects, removed the ppa (mikhailnov). Then I re-installed the ppa and PulseEffects, and it still works just fine. I have a hunch where the issue might be. I need to see the output of `gedit /etc/pulse/default.pa`.

Comment: Bastard this broke my install completely

Comment: Debian 10: `apt install pulseeffects` was all that is needed. Select the equalizer on the left and tweak away, no need to restart anything such as the current music player, everything just works out of the box :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 22):

This is a follow-up (and maybe a bit of a rant) for fans of PulseAudio-Equalizer (PAE) and PulseEffects (PE). As most users have found out by now with Ubuntu 18.04, PAE is no longer supported, having been available for years. For audio fans like myself, this was a very annoying setback as I found the use of PAE noticeably enhanced the sound in Ubuntu giving a really pleasant listening experience. But so far nobody seems to have come up with a workable means of installing PAE with 18.04. However thanks to the info from user Logix we now have PE, so the loss of PAE doesn't seem that important any longer.

[image: PulseEffects]

PE has a lot more bells and whistles than PAE although I have little idea what most of them do. I have no instructions or manual that guide me or explain what the various applications within mean. Except we do have an equalizer, the main reason why I installed PE. And that one works in a very similar way to PAE, where you can set your own frequencies or presets and name-save them. I see you can even import them from a file of presets which I saved from PAE, but haven't tried this out yet.

As for downloading and installing PE, until recently this was a real PITA. There is **Github**, but as so often is the case with them, no instructions on how to install that I've come across. So unless you have a degree in Computer Science, good luck with that.  There's also **Flatpak**, which is an alternative to Snap if no package is found in there nor the repositories. The trouble with Flatpak is that it's slow to start from a fresh boot

Then Eureka! Finally, I discovered there's a repository and the more conventional Debian method of installing packages and which nearly always works *out of the box*, so here are the commands for PE.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mikhailnov/pulseeffects -y
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pulseeffects
```

With the *apt install* command I've seen a suggestion to use these 2 commands together:

`sudo apt install pulseeffects pulseaudio --install-recommends`, but found the 2nd one unnecessary as 18.04 already comes packaged with PulseAudio.

By the way if anyone can tell me how to install PE from Github, just as a learning exercise I'd be curious to know.

Comment: I get a `segmentation fault` when I try to run it : failed to load module-null-sink with argument: sink_name=PulseEffects_mic

Comment: Same here on 18.04: ```(pulseeffects:26966): pulseeffects-CRITICAL **: 18:33:06.052: pulse_manager: failed to load module-null-sink with argument: sink_name=PulseEffects_mic sink_properties=device.description="PulseEffects(mic)"device.class="sound" channels=2 rate=44100
Speicherzugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben)```

Comment: `E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/paolorotolo/droidcam/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.`

Answer (score 7):

Pulse effects didn't work in my case. 
And the new pulseaudio-equalizer (that is called qpaeq in 18.04) has a horrible latency. I spent weeks trying to find the solution, and it looks like there is another option to install pulseaudio-equalizer. Just download the version for 16.04 from [here](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-equalizer
```

Open "pulseaudio-equalizer/usr" folder inside the archive and extract the contents into `/usr/`.
After that, you probably need to install the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install swh-plugins ladspa-sdk python-gtk2 python-glade2 python-gobject python-gnome2
```

When everything is done, you can launch and use it with:

```
pulseaudio-equalizer-gtk
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible autostart this equalizer with a desired configuration?

Comment: There is "Keep settings" option:
http://prntscr.com/kjy33v
If that doesn't help, you need to find default sink settings file in `~/.config/pulse`
For example, `2da220061f824ad198fafb706eecc57a-default-sink`

And save this string there:     ladspa_output.mbeq_1197.mbeq

Comment: You bastard this completely broke my computer