# System wide sound equalizer? ubuntu 18

Tags: sound

the title says it all: is there a system wide sound enhancer/equalizer with a gui for us? ive tried using a few different sources (pulse) to no avail. any help?

thanks for reading :)

Comment: What do you mean when you say "system-wide"

Comment: kind of like the realtek sound effects and equalizer program in windows. like, not just app or program specific equalization, but system wide

Comment: I'm sure that you have noted that PulseAudio-Equalizer seems to be a little problematic.  I run quite a different setup myself (I do some recording) but [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1089593/283721) which installs PulseEffects may work for you.

Comment: yeah, i believe its no longer supported possibly? im going to check the link you shared, and get back with you!

Comment: ok, so ive tried fetching and compiling PE to no avail. maybe im doing something wrong?

Comment: im incredibly new to this, and its showing lol

Comment: We all got to learn somewhere!  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Hm.  I think I know, if your attempting to compile.  I'll type up the required commands in a short answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm paraphrasing from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034101/equalizer-in-ubuntu-18-04/1089593#1089593)

The following commands will install PulseEffects on your computer.  As you are adding a PPA, you should also know how to remove that PPA.

First, install the program for (eventual) PPA removal:

`sudo apt install ppa-purge`

Secondly, add the PPA to your system, do an APT update, and then install PulseEffects

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mikhailnov/pulseeffects -y
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pulseeffects
```

Finally, should you need to remove PulseEffects:

`sudo ppa-purge ppa:mikhailnov/pulseeffects`

Comment: wow, that worked. i tried something very similar yesterday, but after it was all said and done... the only response i got from the system when trying to launch PE, was "it is recommended that you update...something something..." from pulse itself. but then nothing, not any screen or activity. THANK YOU!

Comment: I needed more BASS now I got more BASS thanks!