# Apply graphic EQ to audio out,headphone jack,ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, laptop, equalizer

I would like to apply a graphic EQ to the audio out(headphone jack),so that it would adjust all audio on the computer including on-line sources such as netflix and youtube.Is this possible?I am currently using a Dell Latitude-E6520 laptop.It has an intel i5,dual core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use PulseEffects, which is pretty good (IMO). Details of how to download and install it are found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034101/equalizer-in-ubuntu-18-04/1089593#1089593). It's also now available to install the package directly from Ubuntu Software.