# how to get better sound quality for Ubuntu

Tags: sound

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 and when listening music it has bad sound quality, much worse than in Windows. Is it possible to get the same sound quality?

```
$ lshw -C multimedia

  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1b
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
       version: 35
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: IRQ:124 memory:a1510000-a1513fff
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lshw -c multimedia`.

Comment: What application are you using to listen to sound?

Comment: youtube.com , vlc and try another players. no difference

Comment: First, run `alsamixer`. Check that your audio chip manufacturer is recognised correctly. Also ensure *PCM* is turned up to 100%, master up to 96%. If listening through headphones I have those at about 75% . Close `alsamixer`. I then adjust sound volume from the sound icon on the top bar.

Comment: it can help to receive best quality sound? i have allready edit daemon.cfg. it helps but not a lot, sound became louder and more voluminous. but still worse than windows

Comment: What's daemon.cfg? No such file on Ubuntu.

Comment: etc/pulse/daemon.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You meant `daemon.conf` in the `/etc/pulse` folder, right? I don't know what you changed in there, but see my last paragraph.

The short answer to your question is to install [PulseEffects](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034101/equalizer-in-ubuntu-18-04/1089593#1089593), which I use, where you adjust the graphics equalizer settings. You can save many different settings to suit different speakers or headphones, etc and name-saving them. This gives me an even better sound than Windows. Read my method of installation there, which is the easiest.

But even without PulseEffects, I can still get decent sound quality, which suggests to me that possibly either your sound configuration or drivers are not the correct ones. I would read a suggested solution [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/solved-terrible-sound-in-linux-much-better-in-windows/8203/4) by Calthax, and try that method first and see if it makes any difference.