# How do I get Acer TrueHarmony feature on Ubuntu?

Tags: sound, acer

In my Acer product there is feature called ["Acer TrueHarmony"](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/AE/content/acerdesign-trueharmony) which makes laptop's sound amazing!!

Is it possible to get this feature on Ubuntu? Or may be get similar results?

Comment: Reviewers - Please don't close this question as unclear even though you didn't know how to answer it because someone else did know how to answer it. Don't be sad, be happy and give the person who answered it credit for his work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems Acer TrueHarmony is what Acer calls their combination of audio hardware and drivers. The hardware, of course, would give the same results regardless of the operating system. I would recommend using the answers from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1034101/899228) to create the audio effects you want.